# SQLite data repeat to show on the screen at new Listfragment

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I use new ListFragment to replace the first ListFragment, the data I called are repeated on the ListView, (the new data will insert at random row in ListView, and old datas still on the screen. Only after activity execute onStop(), the view became normal)
Is there any good way to clear the old data on the view, or replace them with new ListFragment at same time?

MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void updateResult() {

    NoteFragment fragmentResult = new NoteFragment();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.note_fragment, fragmentResult);

    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

ListFragment:

```
public class NoteFragment extends ListFragment {


    private DB mDbHelper;
    private Cursor mCursor = null;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(Debug.log){ Log.d("NoteFragment", "onCreated");}

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setAdapter();
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        if( fm.findFragmentById(R.id.note_fragment)!= null){
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        }

    }


    public void setAdapter(){

        mDbHelper = new DB(getActivity());
        mDbHelper.open();
        if(mCursor == null){
        mCursor = mDbHelper.getAll();
        getActivity().startManagingCursor(mCursor);
        }

        String[] from_column = new String[]{DB.KEY_ITEM, DB.KEY_CREATED};
        int[] to_layout = new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                mCursor, from_column, to_layout);

        setListAdapter(adapter);


        if(Debug.log){ Log.d("NoteFragment", "setAdapter");}

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        getActivity().stopManagingCursor(mCursor);
        mCursor.close();
        mDbHelper.close();
        super.onDestroyView();

    }
```

DB:

```
...
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_ITEM + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_CREATED + " TIMESTAMP"
            + ")";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        if (Debug.log) {
            Log.d("NoteFragment", "DatabaseHelper");
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        if (Debug.log) {
            Log.d("DB", "onCreate");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
        if (Debug.log) {
            Log.d("DB", "onUpgrade");
        }

    }

}


/** Constructor */
public DB(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;

    if (Debug.log) {
        Log.d("DB", "DB");
    }

}


public DB open() throws SQLException {

        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    if (Debug.log) {Log.d("DB", "SQLException");
    }
    return this;
}

public void close() {

    dbHelper.close();
    if (Debug.log) {
        Log.d("DB", "close");
    }

}

public Cursor getAll() {
    mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM history ORDER BY created DESC",
            null);

    return mCursor;
}

// add an entry
public long create(String record) {

    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_ITEM, record);

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm",
            Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date now = new Date();
    args.put(KEY_CREATED, df.format(now.getTime()));
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, args);
}
```

Comment: Just replace the adapter of the view with the new one. Keep separate logic for GUI and data. If you change that view data, no need to redraw or recycle all your GUI.

Comment: I try if(adapter != null) to change a setListAdapter, but it didn't work, could you show me the way?